# Need to change a MYSQL query using the @ as we updated our Mysql version

Tags: mysql, sql, railo

We updated our Mysql Driver to

Database Name   MySQL
Database Version    5.6.10-log
Driver Name MySQL-AB JDBC Driver

We were using an older version but no one knows what that version was as that machine is DEAD. 
The query below is running within our railo web site. The MySQL server does not like the @ but I have no idea how to re-write as MySQL is not my thing and this was code written many many moons ago.

```
set @row = 0;

select nf.nid, @row:=@row+1 as ranking from financial nf 
where nf.year = (select distinct year from financial where type = 'Total income' Order by year DESC LIMIT 1) 
and nf.type in ('Total Spend','Total budget (Spend)') 
and nf.nid in (select ft_no from n where ft_type in (1)) 
and nf.value > 0 
order by nf.value desc
```

If anyone knows Mysql better than me (most people) please help me solve this issue. I am sure you will find more issues with the query so any help is welcomed.

Thanks in advance
Andrea

Comment: What do you mean by "The MySQL server does not like the @"? Is there any error message given?

Comment: Yes that is correct but not the error has disappeared bu the problem is still there. I am trying to recreate but my machone was rebuilt

Comment: This is the error. We needed to turn off a feature. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select nf.nid, @row:=@row+1 as ranking from financial nf 
where nf.yea' at line 2
SQL   I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there is a problem running multiple queries in a single query.  If that is the issue, you can solve this by setting the initial value in the query:

```
select nf.nid, (@row := @row+1) as ranking
from financial nf cross join
     (select @row := 0) params
where nf.year = (select max(year)
                 from financial
                 where type = 'Total income'
                ) and
     nf.type in ('Total Spend', 'Total budget (Spend)') and
     nf.nid in (select ft_no from n where ft_type in (1)) and
     nf.value > 0 
order by nf.value desc;
```

I simplified the subquery for `year` as well.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much